# How to forward public_IP/dashboard of an HTTP server to private_IP/dashboard?

Tags: linux, networking, nat, httpd, ip-forwarding

I have a website which is accessible internally via http://private_IP/dashboard.
The public IP forwards all traffic to the private IP. 
`http://public_IP -> http://private_IP`. This works.

However, `http://public_IP/dashboard -> http://private_IP/dashboard` does not work. How to enable this?

Thanks and regards

Answer (score 0):

This was fixed by finding the dashboard configuration file under /etc/httpd/conf.d and simply adding a server alias with the public IP information. For example;

```
ServerAlias private_IP public_IP
```